# Factor each of the following into two polynomials of degree 1: $x,x+2, x+3$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

This question is on this site but has no answer.

> In $\mathbb Z_6[x]$, factor each of the following into two polynomials of degree 1: $x,x+2, x+3$.

I need help with $x+2$ since 2 is a zero divisor in 6 I am struggling to find some 
 $(ax+b)(cx+d)=x+2$, i.e. $acx^2+(ad+bc)x+bd=x+2$. I need $ad+bc\equiv 1$(mod 6) and $bd\equiv 2$(mod 6). Anything that gives me 2 for $bd$ with affect my $ad+bc$. Could I get some hints?

Comment: Your polynomials already have degree $1$, so you are done. What do you really want?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I want to factor $x+2$ into two polynomials of degree 1.

Comment: By the degree of a polynomial, I mean the greatest $n$ such that the coefficient of $x^n$ is not zero, i.e.$1+2x-3x^2+x^3$ has degree 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have computed, we obtain the condition $2d+3b=1$ and $bd=2$ in the ring $\mathbb{Z}/6$. So we can take $b=1$ and $d=2$:
$$
(2x+1)(3x+2)=6x^2+7x+2=x+2.
$$